# Can I listen port 514 with php?

Tags: php, port

I have a grandstream ATA device , which reports to a SysLog Server all the debug info.
 I have found relative programs on the web which do this and I can actually see the logs
. But is there any class, if it is possible , to make an php application to listen to port ex 514 , or to any port? if not with php what would you advice for a programming lanugage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's something you need to tell your webserver. If you're using apache, see [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html). You need to add `LISTEN 514` to you `httpd.conf` file.